# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' when using $push on sub-document array with getMongoManager updateOne

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to execute the following code snippet to update a sub-document array using the $push operation with getMongoManager's updateOne method from myEntity.service.ts:

```
import { getMongoManager, MongoRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import MyEntity from './entities/myEtity.model';

...

export class MyEntityService{
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
     private MyEntityRepository: MongoRepository<MyEntity>,

....
async addFavoriteProduct(myId: string, productId: string) {

const manager = getMongoManager();

try {
  await manager.updateOne(
    MyEntity,
    { id: myId },
    { $push: { favorite: productId } },
  );
}
} catch (err) {
      Logger.error(
        `Failed to add product `
      );
    }
  }
```

and myEntity.model.ts is

```
import { Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export default class MyEntity  {
  @Column()
  id: string;

....
 @Column({ default: [] })
  favorite?: string[];
}
```

typescript is giving me:

```
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

146         { $push: { favorite: productId } },
```

I can't seem to resolve the issue. Any insights or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Note i am using :  `"@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",` `"mongodb": "4.1",` and `"typeorm": "^0.3.17",`